# Parse Related Items that are not key value pairs

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am using a an application that allows custom field but it saves the field name and field entry as values in the same dictionary. I have the following JSON data that is provided via GET (I don't control the database or the data structure). I need the value for the key that follows the value for the previous key.

I am not sure where to start. If I try using a string reference then I have several duplicate values as everything is saved in *"id":* and *"value":* pairs.

**EXAMPLE:** I want the Customer Name but the field "customer_name" and the value entered are not a key:value pair. How do I parse out the customer name and assign it to the variable customerName?

> If I run *print(customerName)* I would expect the output to be **CUSTOMER A**.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
"customFields": {
  "string": [
    {
        "id": "customer_name",
        "value": "CUSTOMER A"
    },
    {
        "id": "department",
        "value": "BUSINESS DEPARTMENT"
    },
    {
        "id": "associate_alias",
        "value": "jdoe1234"
    },
    {
        "id": "manager_alias",
        "value": "bob6789"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to transform your response into Python dict

```
response = {"customFields": {
  "string": [
    {
        "id": "customer_name",
        "value": "CUSTOMER A"
    },
    {
        "id": "department",
        "value": "BUSINESS DEPARTMENT"
    },
    {
        "id": "associate_alias",
        "value": "jdoe1234"
    },
    {
        "id": "manager_alias",
        "value": "bob6789"
    }]
}}

customer = {i['id']: i['value'] for i in response['customFields']['string']}
print(customer['customer_name'])
```